# How does the ModelStateDictionary in ASP.NET know which model to validate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Take this bit of generated code for example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Bill bill)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(bill).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(bill);
    }
```

There is a Model called "Bill", that has some [Required] attributes set for it.

My question is: how does the ModelState.IsValid know that it should be checking the Bill entity as opposed to another entity?

Comment: The `Edit` method has the `bill` parameter which type's is `Bill`... that is how MVC knows that it should validate the `Bill` type

Comment: So it just reads the parameter? What if I wanted to use the ModelStateDictionary outside of this context (lets say a method with no parameters in a helper class), how would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a default model binder in ASP.NET MVC called `DefaultModelBinder`. This class will automatically execute for each of the action parameters you defined. And when it attempts to instantiate and populate the corresponding model from the request key/value string pairs, it might encounter errors that this model binder simply adds to the `ModelState` dictionary. The reason why it might encounter errors is because you might have decorated your model with validation attributes.

So once the code execution enters the controller action, the `ModelState.IsValid` property will return false if there are errors added to it during model binding.

By the way your code is equivalent to the following (never to be used, just for illustration purposes):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    Bill bill = new Bill();
    if (TryUpdateModel(bill))
    {
        db.Entry(bill).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(bill);
}
```

Comment: To be a little clearer, MVC looks at the parameters of the action method using Reflection, and then walks the public properties of the object(s) passed via the parameter of the method.